# iMessage without iCloud is like or unlike other messaging applications when it comes to the synchronization?

Tags: iphone, ipad, icloud, messages

If one uses the same Apple ID in more than one device and uses iMessage in each device, if iCloud > Message is disabled, ie, the iMessage sync is turned off, don't we "receive" a message on each device and see the "sent" message on each device? I am asking if it's like WhatsApp/Telegram/Messenger/etc or not. Tell me what exactly happens when you have a SIM card installed and when not, the latter being more useful since I anyway use other messaging applications at this point.

This is for mobile devices and not Mac.

Comment: I don’t really get why you’re comparing different services - there’s nothing that makes them all behave the same way or different way. If you don’t get a good answer, consider to editing this to be about a practical problem you face. What are you actually trying to do and how does your research not get you to your answer?

Answer (score 0):

ICloud messaging only keep your messages in sync - it doesn’t *prevent* all your devices from receiving messages and that in and of itself is dependent on how you’ve configured Messages to “reach you.”  In other words, there are several ways that you can be reached - AppleID, alternate email, phone number, etc.

If another iOS user sends you a message via SMS, your iPhone will get it, but your Mac won’t for example (assuming sync is turned off).  However, if someone on a iDevice (iPhone or Mac) sends you a message using your AppleID, both your Mac and iPhone will get it.  However, where you initiate and respond is where you will see the conversation history.  If you reply on your phone, you will not see it on your Mac, for example.

So, using your example of removing the SIM card, you *may* receive a message if connected to WiFi and if you do and respond to it on that iOS device, you won’t see the conversation sync up on your Mac, though you may see the *initial* message.

As for how they relate to WhatsApp/Telegram/et al, it’s completely different technology. Those messaging apps do not interface with your carrier like Messages does and they are entirely self contained within the cloud.  Each client is simply a means to access the cloud based messaging service so each client, by default will be synced up.